# ¿Cómo crear una tabla con unos valores establecidos en SQL para HTML?

Tags: php, html, sql

lo que sucede es que no se como crear esta tabla en HTML a base de la tabla que tengo en SQL que es la siguiente:

La tabla esta denominada: "RESULTADOS"

| id | anio | anio_evaluacion | Alexis | Carlos | Nando | Andres | Julian | Jorge | Julio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 2019 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2020 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 |
| 3 | 2021 | 2021 | 80 | 80 | 80 | 80 | 80 | 80 | 80 |

Y quisiera conseguir la siguiente tabla en HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda esta en si debería crear otra tabla en SQL para generar este resultado o si debería cambiar la estructura de la tabla RESULTADOS para generarla solo con esta.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Qué tal crear una Vista? Qué tal crear un ViewModel? Qué tal crear un procedimiento almacenado y devolver los campos que vas a ocupar? Tendrás que ser más específico, porque a como está escrita, parece que es una pregunta basada en opiniones

Comment: Deberías realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask], así obtendrás tus primeras medallas y aprenderás sobre el funcionamiento de esta comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.